# Linear gradient colour length in HTML not working

Tags: css, html, linear-gradients

I am trying to create a gradient background in HTML with CSS. The gradient should have red colour 10% from the top and the rest part (80%) should be of green colour, something like this:
[image]

For doing this, I wrote this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            html, body{margin: 0; padding:0;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position: fixed; z-index: 1; background: linear-gradient(red 10%, green); height: 100%; width:100%"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
    </script>
</html>
```

But, I am getting this output:
[image]

Please tell what's wrong with my code and how to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're defining the color at particular points. So in your case...

```
 background: linear-gradient(red 10%, green);
```

This means that the div is `red` at 10%. Since you haven't specified otherwise, the browser assumes you want red from 0-10%.

You've also said you want the color to change to `green`, but haven't defined a point where that should happen, so the browser assumes the end of the div (or 100%).

To get the effect you're looking for, you'd need something like this:

```
background: linear-gradient(red, green 20%);
```

This starts at `red` (at 0%), then fades to `green` by the time it reaches 20% mark, and then continues `green` from then on (to 100%).

Comment: Please tell that if I want to add more than 2 colour stops at particular position, how should I write the code?

Comment: Sure. The following code would go from red to green, then immediately change to black: background: linear-gradient(red, green 20%, black 20%);

Comment: Thanks, but the black should be set to more than 20%, because on setting it to 20%, black is displayed as a solid colour.

Comment: But why is this technique not working properly for rgba colours?

Comment: Right -- you can place colors wherever you like. Colors defined at the same point will not have any transition between them. This property accepts all types of CSS color (Hex, named colors, rgba, hsla, etc.)